# Sorting not working in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am creating an index with elastic search and want to be able to sort on the "field" country_en (I might want to add another field later). However the sorting result is not correctly.

A descending order would return

- Czech Republic
- Germany
- France
- Finland
- Czech Republic
- Czech Republic
- Germany
- United Kingdom

When I sort ascending the order is different again, but not on alphabet.

The command I give to create the index is:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_river/tenders/_meta" -d '
{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "servers": [
      { "host": "127.0.0.1", "port": 27017 }
    ],
    "options": { "secondary_read_preference": true },
    "db": "jna",
    "collection": "tenders"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "tenders",
    "type": "string",
    "bulk": {
          "concurrent_requests": 2
    }
  },
  "mappings" : {
        "country" : {
            "_source" : { "enabled" : true },
            "properties" : {
                "country_en" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

The search is done via the elastic search PHP library. The command is an array but I converted it to JSON using PHP json_encode.

```
{
  "body": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "_all",
              "query": "Liability*"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": "25",
    "sort": {
      "country_en": {
        "order": "asc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data that is being indexed

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("53bd88db557acd276d8b4d5f"),
   "userid": null,
   "importdate": ISODate("2014-07-09T18:24:27.0Z"),
   "documentnumber": "230476-2014",
   "source": "ted",
   "typeoftender": "public",
   "categories": {
     "0": ObjectId("5210c86d9b7e7a3803000010")
  },
   "data": {
     "oj": "129",
     "ol": "de",
     "cy": "de",
     "ds": "0.00000000 1404424800",
     "dt": ISODate("2014-08-10T22:00:00.0Z"),
     "aa": NumberLong(1),
     "td": NumberLong(3),
     "nc": NumberLong(2),
     "pr": NumberLong(2),
     "ty": NumberLong(1),
     "ac": NumberLong(1),
     "heading": "01202",
     "cpv": {
         "0": "33600000"
      }
  },
   "type": "public",
   "title_en": "Pharmaceutical products",
   "category_en": "Pharmaceuticals",
   "country_en": "Germany",
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the search you are using to your original post.  Queries that use the scan search type, for example, are not sorted.

ref => http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#search-request-search-type

Comment: @MatthewJ I've updated the post and added the search command. It's actually send by PHP (array) but I converted it to json. Hope things still make sense.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the data you have indexed and a sample incorrect result set?

Comment: @JohnPetrone I've added an example of the dataset. Let em know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how the sort is failing? Also, why do you have "ignore_unmapped": true set in your query?

Comment: @JohnPetrone I've updated the post with the country result in a sort order.

Comment: got it, can you tell me why you are using   "ignore_unmapped": true ?

Comment: Had an error when I did not had this. Documentation said that if you use this it will ignore sorting if the field is not mapped. Link to the document: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Comment: @JohnPetrone I need to do some more testing, but I think you found the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having issues that require ignore_unmapped to be set to true, it would imply that you are having mapping problems. There have been others who have had similar issues with mappings with the MongoDB river. I'd suggest the following course of action:

I would set dynamic mapping to false or set it to strict for the type you are using with river:

> The dynamic creation of mappings for unmapped types can be completely
>   disabled by setting index.mapper.dynamic to false.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html

I would also take a look at this discussion concerning custom mappings and the MongoDB river and in particular how people were able to address it by setting dynamic mapping to false:

https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/issues/75